# How can I write batch file for archiving files being in subdirectories?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to write batch script which will be add to archives files which being in subdirectories. Achieve's name should be as subdirectories name.

For example, I have following structure:

```
file.bat
dir1
-- file1.txt
-- file2.csv
dir2
-- file3.txt
-- file4.csv
```

I want to run file.bat and get two files:

```
dir1.zip
-- file1.txt
-- file2.csv
dir2.zip
-- file3.txt
-- file4.csv
```

I wrote such:

```
FOR /D %%i IN (.\*) DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7za920\7za.exe" a -tzip "%%~ni.zip" "%%i"
```

But I got

```
 dir1.zip
--dir1
--- file1.txt
--- file2.csv
--dir2.zip
--- file3.txt
--- file4.csv
```

It's wrong.

How I can I get right result using 7-zip?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this:

```
FOR /D %%i IN (*) DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7za920\7za.exe" a -tzip "%%~ni.zip" "%%i\*"
```

This will create the ZIP files without the folder name.

```
@echo off
FOR /D %%i IN (*) DO (
   pushd "%%i"
      "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7za920\7za.exe" a -tzip "..\%%~ni.zip" *
   popd
)
pause
```

Comment: Unfortunately, but I got structure as my last in question :(

Comment: It works fine here.  What do you see on the console?

Comment: 7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
Scanning

Creating archive dir2.zip

Compressing  dir2\file2.txt
Compressing  dir2\file4.csv

Everything is Ok

Comment: but I see in. for example, dir1.zip first folder dir1 and then files only. And I need dir1.zip and in it files

Comment: Execute `"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7za920\7za.exe" l "dir1.zip"` and paste the screen output into your question, so I can see what is inside the zip files, and then describe what you need in there.

Comment: Thanks, but this is now working. http://pixs.ru/showimage/Untitledpn_7868314_13955206.png http://pixs.ru/showimage/Untitled1p_2885232_13955218.png http://pixs.ru/showimage/Untitled2p_3715182_13955225.png http://pixs.ru/showimage/Untitled3p_3904047_13955230.png

Comment: I had used `%%a` instead of `%%i` so try the code above now.